# How to use try and except in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I wanted to use try and except in djagno template is there is any way to use it.

I want to check either attendance table has any data of not. and if not it has to show error text

```
{% try %}
    {% for attendances in attendance %}
        ....
    {% endfor %}
{% except %}
    <h1>Error Attendance table has no data.</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of try-catch, you can use Django's built-in [for..empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) template tag.

```
{% for attendances in attendance %}
        ....
{% empty %}
    <h1>Error Attendance table has no data.</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

This will show the error message if the table is empty.